# sorting selected items in an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have got an array that contains data in hierarchical form such as:

```
Level 2
  chapter 1
  chapter 2
Level 4
  chapter 1
  chapter 2
Level 1
  chapter 1
  chapter 2
Level 3
  chapter 1
  chapter 2
```

If I just call `array.sort()`, the hierarchy gets disturbed.  So, I have to develop my own way of sorting items.   The thing I can't understand is, how would I compare two levels such that I would know that level 1 is less than level 2 and it should be at the top index of the array?

Comment: I have no idea what your array looks like...

Comment: How does this array get formed? Is it really an `Array` or just an `Object`

Comment: is your array flat? like `['level2', 'chapter1', 'chater2', 'level4']` etc

Comment: Does this mean arrays in arrays?

Comment: No this is an array that contains these strings. array[0]=level 2, array[1]=chapter 1, array[3]=level 4 and so on...so its a flat array!!

Comment: @Salman That array is badly designed. Why? Did you construct it?

Comment: i hav got a php function that returns the directory structure in this flat array!! what data structure shud i use then? if nt this!!

Comment: @Salman One possibility: http://jsfiddle.net/PFY6p/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using a flat array. You lose all the hierarchical information. Something like this would be better:

```
//I've deliberately made these unsorted to show you that sorting works
levels = ["Level 4", "Level 3", "Level 1", "Level 2"];

data = {
  "Level 3" : ["chapter 1", "chapter 2"],
  "Level 1" : ["chapter 2", "chapter 1"],
  "Level 2" : ["chapter 2", "chapter 1"],
  "Level 4" : ["chapter 1", "chapter 2"]  
};

levels.sort();
for(var i = 0 i < levels.length; i++) {
    console.log(levels[i]);
    var chapters = data[levels[i]];

    chapters.sort();    
    for(var j = 0; j < chapters.length; j++) {
        console.log(chapters[j]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Rob suggested using `levels.sort(function(x,y){return x.localeCompare(y)})` instead of the regular `.sort()`. The former will sort `["abc", "Abcd", "Ab"]` to `["Ab", "abc", "Abcd"]` instead of `["Ab", "Abcd", "abc"]`.

Comment: Your extra comma in the data array will make IE barf.

Comment: Another note:
Use `levels.sort(function(x,y){return x.localeCompare(y)})` instead of a plain `.sort()`. The normal sort function would sort `["abc", "Abcd", "Ab"]` to `["Ab", "Abcd", "abc"]`. My proposal would result `["Ab", "abc", "Abcd"]`.

Comment: @Jens That was a copy-pasta syntax error. Rob Thanks! I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should reformat the flat PHP array to the nicer JS object:

```
var fromPHP = ['Level 2','chapter 1','chapter 2','Level 4','chapter 1','chapter 2','Level 1','chapter 1','chapter 2','Level 3','chapter 1','chapter 2'];

var levels = [],
    betterArray = [fromPHP[0]],
    currentLevel=betterArray[0];

for (var i=1;i<fromPHP.length;i++) {
  if (fromPHP[i].substr(0,5) == 'Level') {
    currentLevel = [];
    levels.push(fromPHP[i]);
    betterArray[fromPHP[i]] = currentLevel;
  } else {
    currentLevel.push(fromPHP[i]);
  }
}
```

Should give the following `levels` and `betterArray`:

```
// levels:
['Level 4','Level 3','Level 1','Level 2']

// betterArray:
{
    'Level 2': ['chapter 1','chapter 2'],
    'Level 4': ['chapter 1','chapter 2'],
    'Level 1': ['chapter 1','chapter 2'],
    'Level 3': ['chapter 1','chapter 2']
}
```

Now you can run whatever sorting you want on the subarrays and get what you wanted.